# Verify Docker Buildx build actually uses the native node

Tags: linux, docker, qemu, buildx

How do I verify a Docker Buildx build actually uses the native node for a given platform?

I have a QEMU-base multi-platform Buildx builder called `maven` on x64 Linux. To that I appended a Mac Mini as native node for Arm builds.

```
$ docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE  DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS   BUILDKIT PLATFORMS
builder    docker-container                              
  builder0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock inactive          
maven *    docker-container                              
  maven0   unix:///var/run/docker.sock running  v0.11.0  linux/amd64*, linux/amd64/v2, linux/arm64, ....
  mac-mini ssh://some-user@10.1.2.3    running  v0.11.5  linux/arm64*, linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, ...
```

Also, I verified the setup actually works by building a "Hello World" image.

```
$ docker buildx build --progress plain --builder maven --platform linux/arm64,linux/amd64 --tag my-hello-world .
...
#8 [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim
#8 DONE 1.0s

#6 [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim
#6 DONE 0.9s
...
```

The question is: did Docker actually use the native node for the Arm build or maybe still the local QEMU "node"? The output doesn't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Buildx driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_create/#driver) `docker-container` creates a `moby/buildkit` container on each node. The name of the container is `buildx_buildkit_<node-name>`. You can poke around that container to understand what it's doing.

Hence, either on the "local" host or on the remote Mac Mini do

- `$ docker ps` to verify what the container name is e.g. `buildx_buildkit_mac-mini` in my case
- `$ docker exec -ti buildx_buildkit_mac-mini sh` to get console access to that running container
- `$ top` inside the container to monitor processes

Inside those containers PID 1 is always `buildkitd`. Other process will be started if you start a Buildx build and Docker assigns work to this node. Examples below.

**Idle**
[image]

**Busy**
[image]